# Homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

We know that $D^n = \{x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|<1\} $ homeomorphic to $S^n_+ = \{x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:\|x\|=1, x_{n+1}\geqslant 0\}$ and homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n.$ 
**Because** **$D^n$ và $\mathbb{R}^n$ are local compact space thus $S^n_+$ also local compact space.**

But n = 1, $S^1_+ = \{x = (x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x_1^2 + x^2_2 = 1, x_2\geqslant 0\}$ homeomorphic to $[0;1]$,**but $[0;1]$ is compact thus $S^1_+$ is compact.**

**Question: $S^n_+ = \{x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:\|x\|=1, x_{n+1}\geqslant 0\}$ is local compact space or compact space??Help me!**

Comment: Replace $x_{n+1} \ge 0$ by $x_{n+1} > 0$

Comment: Thanks you very much! $S^n_+ = \{x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:||x||=1, x_{n+1}>0\}$ ($x_{n+1}>0$) is not homeomorphic to $S^n_+ = \{x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:||x||=1, x_{n+1}\geqslant 0\}.$  true or false??

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  Read it again, and be very careful about whether you mean $>$ or $\geq$ in each case.  Then perhaps we can help you.

Comment: True. The one with $\ge$ is compact, the other one is not.

Comment: Oh,Thanks Thomas!